# How to add two or more sessions in add member telegram

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

Wanted to know how to add two account sessions so they alternately add members of a group but when i use: client2(InviteToChannelRequest(target_group_entity,[user_to_add])) error occurs from different channels. I'm trying to add my group members to another channel.
This code has already started the two sessions, the first one is more configured and I wanted to know what to do for the second session to work

```
#First Session
api_id = xxxx    #Your Api ID
api_hash = 'xxxx'    #Your Api Hash
phone = 'xxxx'      # Your Phone Number With Country Code.
client = TelegramClient(phone, api_id, api_hash)
client.connect()
print(client.get_me().username, '- Sucessfully Connected! ')

if not client.is_user_authorized():
    client.send_code_request(phone)
    client.sign_in(phone)
    try:
        client.sign_in(code=input('Enter code: '))
    except SessionPasswordNeededError:
        client.sign_in(password=getpass.getpass())
time.sleep(5)

#Second Session
api_id2 = xxxx    #Your Api ID
api_hash2 = 'xxxx'    #Your Api Hash
phone2 = '+xxxxx'      # Your Phone Number With Country Code.
client2 = TelegramClient(phone2, api_id2, api_hash2)
client2.connect()
print(client2.get_me().username, '- Sucessfully Connected! ')

if not client2.is_user_authorized():
    client2.send_code_request(phone2)
    client2.sign_in(phone2)
    try:
        client2.sign_in(code=input('Enter code: '))
    except SessionPasswordNeededError:
        client2.sign_in(password=getpass.getpass())
time.sleep(5)

def add_users_to_group():
    users = []
    with open(r"scrapped", encoding='UTF-8') as f:
        rows = csv.reader(f,delimiter=",",lineterminator="\n")
        next(rows, None)
        for row in rows:
            user = {}
            user['username'] = row[0]
            try:
                user['id'] = int(row[1])
                user['access_hash'] = int(row[2])
            except IndexError:
                print ('users without id or access_hash')
            users.append(user)

random.shuffle(users)
chats = []
last_date = None
chunk_size = 10
groups=[]

result = client(GetDialogsRequest(
            offset_date=last_date,
            offset_id=0,
            offset_peer=InputPeerEmpty(),
            limit=chunk_size,
            hash = 0
        ))
chats.extend(result.chats)

for chat in chats:
    try:
        if chat.megagroup== True: #Condition To Only List Megagroups
            groups.append(chat)
    except:
        continue

#print('Choose a group to add members:')
i=0
print("\n|-|-|-|-| GRUPOS |-|-|-|-|")
for group in groups:
    print(str(i) + '- ' + group.title)
    firstname = groups[i].title
    if firstname.split()[0] == "Grupo":
        g_index = i;
    i = i + 1
print("\n")
target_group=groups[int(g_index)]

target_group_entity = InputPeerChannel(target_group.id,target_group.access_hash)

#mode = int(input("Enter 1 to add by username or 2 to add by ID: "))

error_count = 0

try:
    if user['username'] == "":
        print ("Adicionando {}".format(user['id']))
    else:
        print ("Adicionando {}".format(user['username']))
    user_to_add = InputPeerUser(user['id'], user['access_hash'])
    client(InviteToChannelRequest(target_group_entity,[user_to_add]))
    print("Espere 60 Segundos...")
    time.sleep(60)
except PeerFloodError:
    print("Obtendo o erro de flood do telegrama. Você deve interromper o script agora. Tente novamente depois de algum tempo.")
except UserPrivacyRestrictedError:
    print("As configurações de privacidade do usuário não permitem que você faça isso. Pulando.")
except:
    traceback.print_exc()
    print("Erro inesperado")
    error_count += 1
    if error_count > 10:
        sys.exit('Muitos erros!')

def list_users_in_group():
    chats = []
    last_date = None
    chunk_size = 200
    groups=[]

result = client(GetDialogsRequest(
            offset_date=last_date,
            offset_id=0,
            offset_peer=InputPeerEmpty(),
            limit=chunk_size,
            hash = 0
        ))
chats.extend(result.chats)

for chat in chats:
    try:
        print(chat)
        groups.append(chat)
        # if chat.megagroup== True:
    except:
        continue


mode = 2
add_users_to_group()
```

Comment: "when i use: client2(...) error occurs from different channels" - what error? What does it say?

Comment: "Invalid channel object. Make sure to pass thre right types, for instance making sure that request is designed for channels or otherwise look for a diferent one more suited (caused by InviteToChannelRequest)"

Comment: Does the client2 have permissions to inv people? Make sure you're in the channel and have the same role as the other one.

Comment: is that as they are the same channel I thought I could minimize the code. but do i really have to do the same things as the other channel to work? thanks for listening

Comment: "when i use: client2(...) error occurs from different channels" II managed to fix the error, I did it exactly on both accounts and it worked thanks